# Why does Safari render svg g with edge/border?

Tags: svg, safari

```
<svg width="29px" height="29px" viewBox="36 168 29 29" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <!-- Generator: Sketch 40.3 (33839) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
  <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g id="checkbox" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(38.000000, 169.000000)">
      <ellipse id="checkbox-circle" stroke="#F2B91A" stroke-width="3" cx="12.5" cy="13.5" rx="12.5" ry="12.5"></ellipse>
      <g id="checkbox-checked" transform="translate(4.000000, 0.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
          <path d="M19.945968,0.293195745 C19.727568,0.141280851 19.486068,0.0470042553 19.229448,0.014387234 C18.587688,-0.0727404255 17.969868,0.241365957 17.620428,0.80747234 L8.299788,15.9252383 L3.003168,8.72089787 C2.693628,8.29866383 2.194248,8.04711064 1.668828,8.04711064 C1.293348,8.04711064 0.929628,8.17713191 0.645288,8.41394043 C0.291648,8.70749362 0.067368,9.13017447 0.012768,9.60468511 C-0.041832,10.0787489 0.079968,10.5465574 0.355908,10.9227702 L7.084308,20.0734085 C7.361088,20.4491745 7.758408,20.688217 8.163288,20.7387064 L8.229228,20.7494298 C8.297268,20.758366 8.364888,20.7619404 8.432088,20.7619404 C8.998248,20.7619404 9.522408,20.4607915 9.834048,19.9554511 L20.429808,2.76806809 C20.937168,1.94370638 20.720448,0.833834043 19.945968,0.293195745 M10.3519546,20.7619404 L0,20.7619404 L0,8.93617021e-05 L20.7039,8.93617021e-05 L20.7039,20.7619404 L10.3519546,20.7619404 L9.25523634e-06,20.7619404 L9.25523634e-06,4.17649403e-07 L20.7040592,4.17649403e-07 L20.7040592,20.7619404 L10.3519546,20.7619404 L10.3519546,20.7619404 Z" id="Combined-Shape"></path>
      </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Problem is that Safari renders a small border for the checkbox-checked g:

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxrhz.png)

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjGmGE?editors=1000#0

**Edit:**
It was actually in the path. Other browsers just don't render it.
Proper path:

```
    <g id="checkbox-checked" transform="translate(4.000000, 0.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
        <path d="M19.945968,0.293195745 C19.727568,0.141280851 19.486068,0.0470042553 19.229448,0.014387234 C18.587688,-0.0727404255 17.969868,0.241365957 17.620428,0.80747234 L8.299788,15.9252383 L3.003168,8.72089787 C2.693628,8.29866383 2.194248,8.04711064 1.668828,8.04711064 C1.293348,8.04711064 0.929628,8.17713191 0.645288,8.41394043 C0.291648,8.70749362 0.067368,9.13017447 0.012768,9.60468511 C-0.041832,10.0787489 0.079968,10.5465574 0.355908,10.9227702 L7.084308,20.0734085 C7.361088,20.4491745 7.758408,20.688217 8.163288,20.7387064 L8.229228,20.7494298 C8.297268,20.758366 8.364888,20.7619404 8.432088,20.7619404 C8.998248,20.7619404 9.522408,20.4607915 9.834048,19.9554511 L20.429808,2.76806809 C20.937168,1.94370638 20.720448,0.833834043 19.945968,0.293195745" id="Combined-Shape"></path>
    </g>
```

Comment: That's what you have in your path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines you are complaining about are actually a part of your path.  If we draw it with a stroke instead of a fill, you can see what I mean.

```html
<svg viewBox="36 168 29 29">
  <g id="checkbox" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(38.000000, 169.000000)">
     <g id="checkbox-checked" transform="translate(4.000000, 0.000000)">
        <path d="M19.945968,0.293195745 C19.727568,0.141280851 19.486068,0.0470042553 19.229448,0.014387234 C18.587688,-0.0727404255 17.969868,0.241365957 17.620428,0.80747234 L8.299788,15.9252383 L3.003168,8.72089787 C2.693628,8.29866383 2.194248,8.04711064 1.668828,8.04711064 C1.293348,8.04711064 0.929628,8.17713191 0.645288,8.41394043 C0.291648,8.70749362 0.067368,9.13017447 0.012768,9.60468511 C-0.041832,10.0787489 0.079968,10.5465574 0.355908,10.9227702 L7.084308,20.0734085 C7.361088,20.4491745 7.758408,20.688217 8.163288,20.7387064 L8.229228,20.7494298 C8.297268,20.758366 8.364888,20.7619404 8.432088,20.7619404 C8.998248,20.7619404 9.522408,20.4607915 9.834048,19.9554511 L20.429808,2.76806809 C20.937168,1.94370638 20.720448,0.833834043 19.945968,0.293195745 M10.3519546,20.7619404 L0,20.7619404 L0,8.93617021e-05 L20.7039,8.93617021e-05 L20.7039,20.7619404 L10.3519546,20.7619404 L9.25523634e-06,20.7619404 L9.25523634e-06,4.17649403e-07 L20.7040592,4.17649403e-07 L20.7040592,20.7619404 L10.3519546,20.7619404 L10.3519546,20.7619404 Z" id="Combined-Shape"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Load the file into your editor and delete the extra lines.